# How to prevent filling tables inside jQuery tabs every time the page loads?

Tags: php, jquery-ui, tabs, smarty

I'm using smarty and I have two tabs where each tab contains a table. When the page loads at first, the two tables load data. Then every time the page is requested because of a button click (I use Ajax buttons), the two tables load data again.

**What I want to do**:

If I'm currently on the first tab, I just want to reload the first table.
and If I'm currently on the second tab, I just want to reload the second one. How can I achieve that?

I tried to use the `$_SESSION` variable, but it didn't help.

Also I tried to use a boolean variables that is true when I press the button and when I'm on the desired selected tab (I use a hidden input = selected tab in each tab). It didn't work either.

Can you suggest a way? It's a if condition, I guess...

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: @jochenJung I solved by myself I'll post the solution